# Adding comments to a node via drush or commandline

Tags: 7, drush, comments

I'm trying to set up a server documentation system using drupal 7. Each server would have it's own page/ node. Updates or changes made to the system would be noted as comments on the servers page. What I'm looking to do is to be able to add a comment via drush or some other command line tool so that I can create an alias on each server to add a comment to that servers page.  I'm not a programmer so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on [Shawn Conn's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/179543/1908), below is a Drush command that adds a comment to a Drupal 7 node.

Usage:

```
drush add-comment --uid=1 --subject='A comment' 'This is my awesome comment.'
```

Save the script below as `add_comment.drush.inc`, and place it in your `$HOME/.drush` directory.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_drush_command().
 */
function add_comment_drush_command() {
  $items = array();

  $items['add-comment'] = array(
    'description' => "Add a comment to a node.",
    // Describe the arguments for this command.  Delete
    // this seciton if command takes no arguments.
    'arguments' => array(
      'comment' => 'The comment to add.',
    ),
    // List all options used for this command. Only options that
    // are listed here (or that are global Drush options) may
    // be specified on the commnadline; all others raise an error.
    'options' => array(
      'nid' => array(
        'description' => 'The node id to add the comment to.',
        'example-value' => '3',
      ),
      'subject' => 'The comment subject. Defaults to empty.',
      'uid' => 'The user id of the user to post the comment as. Defaults to anonymous.',
    ),
    // Give one or more example commandline usages for this command
    'examples' => array(
      'drush add-comment --nid=123 "This is my great comment."' => 'Do something.',
    ),
    'aliases' => array('addc'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_drush_help().
 *
 * @param
 *   A string with the help section (prepend with 'drush:')
 *
 * @return
 *   A string with the help text for your command.
 */
function add_comment_drush_help($section) {
  switch ($section) {
    case 'drush:add-comment':
      return dt("Brief help for Drush command add-comment.");
    // The 'title' meta item is used to name a group of
    // commands in `drush help`.  If a title is not defined,
    // the default is "All commands in ___", with the
    // specific name of the commandfile (e.g. add-comment).
    // Command files with less than four commands will
    // be placed in the "Other commands" section, _unless_
    // they define a title.  It is therefore preferable
    // to not define a title unless the file defines a lot
    // of commands.
    case 'meta:add-comment:title':
      return dt("add-comment commands");
    // The 'summary' meta item is displayed in `drush help --filter`,
    // and is used to give a general idea what the commands in this
    // command file do, and what they have in common.
    case 'meta:add-comment:summary':
      return dt("Summary of all commands in this command group.");
  }
}

/**
 * Implementation of drush_hook_COMMAND().
 *
 * Add a comment to a node.
 */
function drush_add_comment($comment) {
  $nid = drush_get_option('nid');
  $uid = drush_get_option('uid', 0);
  $subject = drush_get_option('subject', '');

  $comment = (object) array(
    'nid' => $nid,
    'cid' => 0,
    'pid' => 0,
    'uid' => $uid,
    'mail' => '',
    'is_anonymous' => ($uid == 0),
    'homepage' => '',
    'status' => COMMENT_PUBLISHED,
    'subject' => $subject,
    'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    'comment_body' => array(
      LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
        0 => array (
          'value' => $comment,
          'format' => 'filtered_html'
        )
      )
    ),
  );

  comment_submit($comment);
  comment_save($comment);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the command how-to. I was going to mention that as an option, but my answer length was already getting unwieldy for a succinct answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things you need to know here: how to create Drush script and how to add a Drupal comment programmatically.

- A [Drush script](http://www.drush.org/en/master/shellscripts/) is like a shell script that boots into the Drupal environment via Drush. Essentially, it's a PHP code script prefixed with `#!/usr/bin/env` drush or `#!/full/path/to/drush` instead of the `<?php` tag.
- Creating a comment programmatically is pretty easy in Drupal. There's an [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14526748/2258752) that gives you a snippet on how to do it.

With that, you can create an executable script (e.g. `chmod +x add_comment.drush`) that can take a few arguments to comment on a node id with a specified title/body:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env drush

  //Check for valid args
  $args = drush_get_arguments();
  if(isset($args[2]) && isset($args[3]) && isset($args[4])) {
    $nid = $args[2];
    $title = $args[3];
    $body = $args[4];

    //@TODO: Any further checks

    //Create comment object and save it
    $comment = (object) array(
      'nid' => $nid,
      'cid' => 0,
      'pid' => 0,
      'uid' => 1,
      'mail' => '',
      'is_anonymous' => 0,
      'homepage' => '',
      'status' => COMMENT_PUBLISHED,
      'subject' => $title,
      'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
      'comment_body' => array(
        LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
          0 => array (
            'value' => $body,
            'format' => 'filtered_html'
          )
        )
      ),
    );
    comment_submit($comment);
    comment_save($comment);
  }
```

In the above example, this script named **add_comment.drush** could be executed with the command `./add_comment.drush 100 "TITLE" "COMMENT"` to add a comment on node ID#100 with `"TITLE"` as the header and `"COMMENT"` as the comment body.